# How to tail a log file when removing lines (not appending) of the file?

Tags: log, tail

I want to know how to tail a log file when lines in the files are updating(appending and removing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Atari911 said](https://askubuntu.com/a/411595/72576), you can use `watch` along with `cat` to do this. Use

```
watch cat <filename>
```

this will output the contents of the file given by `filename` every 2 seconds to standard output. To change the interval for updating the output to something like 1 second(you can't reduce beyond 0.1), you can use

```
watch -n 1 cat <filename>
```

I am using cat to output the complete file, you could tail but that would only give you the last `n` lines of the file, where `n` is 10 by default.

Refer to the manual page of [watch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Or whatever file you are interested in. Get out of 'tail' with Ctrl+c.

Comment: This is not working when lines are removing from the file

Comment: I am unaware of any log file where lines are _removed_. Which is it?

Comment: It's relevant to my application

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the tail command which output the last part of files in real time including all incoming logs to a standard output device such as screen. the commadn to use is

```
tail -f /path/to/log/file
```

EDIT: TRY this

```
tail -f --retry /path-to-log-file
```

This will try to reopen the file with the new contents

Or this

```
tail -F /path/to/log/file
```

Comment: This is not working when lines are removing from the file

Comment: @LasithMalinga check the edit

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do but you could use the `watch` command in conjunction with the `tail` command... Something like this:

`watch tail /path/to/file`